# WPF Scrollbar over content

Tags: wpf, styles, scrollbar

I am working on a custom style for the scrollbar on the scrollviewer. It is working fine but I want the scrollbar to be on top of the content so my controls width won't break because of the scrollbar.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPah.png]

As you can see here the control on top breaks because of the scrollbar. Do you guys know how to make my scrollbars background some kind of transparent so my control will be behind the scrollbar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Resource**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListboxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Resources>             

            <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumbVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#CDCDCD" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#A6A6A6"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#606060"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>                                       
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Bg" Width="8" Margin="0,15,0,15" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition  MaxHeight="0"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <RepeatButton Height="0" Width="0" x:Name="PART_LineUpButton" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"/>                                                                           
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbVertical}"/>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                </Track>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineDownButton" Height="0" Width="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="2"/>                                  
                            </Grid>                    
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>                   
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">                                  
                                <ScrollContentPresenter   x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow"  Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListboxStyle}" Height="400" Width="150" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="29/6/2014 9:58:00 Datetime value" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
</ListBox>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Wow not bad! Thank you very much. What about the space the invisible space between the scrollbar itself and the increase / decrease buttons?

Comment: i had to made some changes to your scrollview style.
<Grid x:Name="Grid" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...


and for PART_ScrollContentPresenter i have setted the column="0"

Comment: This is an excellent solution! Note that the main magic is done in the `ScrollViewer` template override. I like that instead of having to add more code/markup, you simply have to remove some elements from the original template. With a few tweaks its easy to customize it any way you need!

Comment: Great, but I can't display the horizontal scrollbar, how do I do that?

Comment: @CodingNinja : you need to add and edit style of ScrollBar x:Name="PART_horizontalScrollBar". For that need to update whole template of scrollviewer .Thanks

Comment: @HeenaPatil I tried, then failed, then tried again and it actually worked, I've forgotten what minor code changes I made...(*￣3￣)╭

Answer (score 3):

The `ScrollBar` is placed in a `Grid` by the parent `ScrollViewer`, so you'll need to provide a new `ControlTemplate` for that. You can use the `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` to make the `ScrollViewer` content stretch to fill the available space. Try something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                        Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{
                        TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{
                        TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Background="Transparent" />
                    <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{TemplateBinding 
                        HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" 
                        Background="Transparent" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: May want to change the ScrollContentPresenter to <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>, otherwise if you use this style globally, without keys, it will interfere with any control that uses an embedded ScrollViewer (like TextBoxes) causing the text to not scroll as you type.